# WPF performance, terrible lag on textBox

Tags: .net, wpf, performance

last few days, we faced serious problems with the WPF performance.
When one keep the key pressed in a textbox, terrible lag appears. The
characters simply don't appear immediately but it takes some time.

Have you ever experienced a similar problem sometimes?

Many thanks for any help,
Ondrej

Comment: Can you give us more details?  Did you recently change any of the events?  Did you change your data binding?  etc etc etc

Comment: No, we have verified all the event handlers registered, no handler is registered for the textbox. The databinding is not set to UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, so nothing is really happening when you just type a text in control till you escape it.

Comment: That is not a WPF problem. It's a problem with your application. It doesn't happen in ours, and we have a BIG Line-Of-Business app. try to isolate the textbox outside the application with its associated functionality to see what might be causing the issue.

Comment: Well, since this is a big line-of-business application as well which is running properly on another machines, I can not be completely sure the problem is in the code. And furthermore it is quite hard to isolate it.

Comment: add another textbox, is it lag too? or, just this one textbox lag?

Comment: All the textBoxes suffer with the same problem

Comment: you may want to check your Keyboard settings from ControlPanel. Check Repeat delay and Repeat Rate.

Comment: It seems that the Repeat delay and Repeat Rate don't have any affect .

Comment: If this runs fine on some machines that is detail you should have included in the question.   How many machines have this problem?